# OpenVPN not starting tun0

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn, raspberry-pi

I have restored a Raspberry Pi running an OpenVPN client from a major disaster by actually copying files in `/etc/openvpn` to the new machine.

Now simply openvpn won't start `dev tun0`

Log shows the following (verbosity 3):

```
Tue Jan 31 20:08:34 2017 OpenVPN 2.3.4 arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jan 23 2016
Tue Jan 31 20:08:34 2017 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016, LZO 2.08
Tue Jan 31 20:08:35 2017 WARNING: file '/etc/ssl/vpn/secret.key' is group or others accessible
Tue Jan 31 20:08:35 2017 WARNING: file '/etc/ssl/vpn/ta.key' is group or others accessible
Tue Jan 31 20:08:35 2017 Control Channel Authentication: using '/etc/ssl/vpn/ta.key' as a OpenVPN static key file
Tue Jan 31 20:08:35 2017 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue Jan 31 20:08:35 2017 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue Jan 31 20:08:35 2017 Socket Buffers: R=[163840->131072] S=[163840->131072]
Tue Jan 31 20:08:35 2017 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Tue Jan 31 20:08:35 2017 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Tue Jan 31 20:08:35 2017 GID set to nogroup
Tue Jan 31 20:08:35 2017 UID set to nobody
Tue Jan 31 20:08:35 2017 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Tue Jan 31 20:08:35 2017 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]aa.bb.cc.dd:1194
Tue Jan 31 20:08:35 2017 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]aa.bb.cc.dd:1194, sid=4c0e5dbf 708c5f57
Tue Jan 31 20:08:36 2017 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=AT, ST=LA, L=ATLANTIS, O=coolpeople, OU=VPN, CN=coolpeople CA, name=djechelon, emailAddress=ca@coolpeople.org
Tue Jan 31 20:08:36 2017 VERIFY OK: nsCertType=SERVER
Tue Jan 31 20:08:36 2017 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=AT, ST=LA, L=ATLANTIS, O=coolpeople, OU=VPN, CN=limortacci, name=djechelon, emailAddress=ca@coolpeople.org
Tue Jan 31 20:08:37 2017 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
Tue Jan 31 20:08:37 2017 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue Jan 31 20:08:37 2017 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
Tue Jan 31 20:08:37 2017 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue Jan 31 20:08:37 2017 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 2048 bit RSA
Tue Jan 31 20:08:37 2017 [limortacci] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]aa.bb.cc.dd:1194
Tue Jan 31 20:08:38 2017 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

But ifconfig shows no trace of `tun0` unless I use `-a`

```
ifconfig tun0
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          POINTOPOINT NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I expected at least tun0 to get the IP address as the server has.

What is wrong with my configuration? It looks like the VPN is established.

Client config is

```
dev tun
proto udp
tls-client
remote aa.bb.cc.dd 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
ca /etc/ssl/vpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/ssl/vpn/cert.crt
key /etc/ssl/vpn/key.key
ns-cert-type server
tls-auth /etc/ssl/vpn/ta.key 1
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
push "route 192.168.192.0 255.255.255.0 vpn_gateway 1"
log         /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 7
```

Files in `/etc/ssl` are present (did I say I restored them too?)

Comment: The logs show that the tun file is created (as you can see with `ifconfig -a`), and that it receives pings, but not if an actual connection is established (it probably isn't, otherwise the interface would be in `UP` state), and what goes wrong with that. Please include these parts of the log.

Comment: Will be done this evening. Actually the pings are the last log statements. They just cycle. I have checked the server and once the client connects the server will issue route commands to itself (because server **knows** the client's subnet, hardcoded)

Comment: Sorry for delay. Question edited with fresh logs

Comment: The next thing that should happen after "Peer Connection Initiated" is a push/pull request exchange. Are you sure the "push" in your config is correct? Maybe you need to do a "pull"?

Comment: Great! I just had to add `pull` to my client config to make `tun0` appear. This is definitely weird because I backed up my configuration during the system failure, so I expected it to work again. My push **is** anyway correct because I want both sides of the tunnel to see each other. I used to print remotely with the two `raspi`es

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next thing that should happen after "Peer Connection Initiated" is a push/pull request exchange. Apparently the other side is doing a *push*, but not a *pull*, so you also need to do a *pull* on this side.